# Bootstrap 4 Navbar: right-aligned dropdown menu opens on the right: overflow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 for a very simple navbar, I just noticed that my right-aligned dropdown opens... on the right which creates an overflow (ie. the horizontal scrollbar of the webbrowser is showing up).

This is the code the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recipes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping List</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Manage
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the related codepen: https://codepen.io/ehouarn-perret/pen/MLoGdE

How to make that right-aligned dropdown to open the menu on the left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `dropdown-menu-right` to your `dropdown-menu` class, like this:

```
   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
   </div>
```

This will align your dropdown menu to the right, instead of the default that is to the left.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Recipes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping List</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav dropleft">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Manage
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fetch Data</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the `_dropdown.scss` of Bootstrap is setting `left: 0px` to `.dropdown-menu`.

If you add the below to your CSS, it should override this.

```
.dropdown-menu { 
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Perhaps add a unique class and target that so that you don't break anything else.

Answer (score 1):

according to [Dropdown menu causes scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873638/dropdown-menu-causes-scrollbar)

adding dropdown-menu-right to your dropdown-menu should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that one before.